# Is Twitter Typeahead.js library limited to 6 datasets?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am using [Typeahed.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) library from Twitter to search multiple datasets in my database from a single input box.

I am currently using 6 data-sets (see the code below) and I want to add 1 more. I found it not working for the 7th datasets (`products dataset` from below code). When typing search query into input box it would only sent GET AJAX requests for first six datasets and would ignore the 7th one?

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_orders.json?q=MSI-20mA
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_invoices.json?q=MSI-20mA
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_services.json?q=MSI-20mA%
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_serials.json?q=MSI-20mA%
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_users.json?q=MSI-20mA%
GET http://127.0.0.1/app/typeahead_licenses.json?q=MSI-20mA%
```

The library docs are pour and I haven't seen it mention any kind of limit on number of datasets you can use...

```
$('#search-query').typeahead([
    {
        name: 'orders',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_orders.json?q=%QUERY",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'orders/view/{{order_id}}">{{value}} - Reference no.: {{reference_number}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Orders</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'invoices',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_invoices.json?q=%QUERY",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'invoices/view/{{invoice_id}}">{{invoice_number}} - {{company}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-file"></i> Invoices</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'services',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_services.json?q=%QUERY%",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'services/view/{{rma_id}}">{{value}} - {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> RMA services</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'serials',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_serials.json?q=%QUERY%",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'serials/view/{{serial_id}}">{{value}} - {{product}} {{module_name}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-barcode"></i> Serials</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'users',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_users.json?q=%QUERY%",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'users?f=1&filter_id={{user_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}} - {{email}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-user"></i> Users</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'licenses',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_licenses.json?q=%QUERY%",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'licenses?f=1&filter_id={{license_id}}">{{key}} - {{version}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Licenses</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'products',
        remote: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_products.json?q=%QUERY%",
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'products?f=1&filter_id={{product_id}}">{{code}} - {{name}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Products</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    }
]).on('typeahead:selected', function($e, data) {
    window.location = data.url;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. It is not limited, but default max parallel request is 6. From the typeahead.js docs:

```
maxParallelRequests – The max number of parallel requests typeahead.js can have pending. Defaults to 6.
```

So I have increased this and it works. Here is the final corrected code:

```
$('#search-query').typeahead([
    {
        name: 'orders',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_orders.json?q=%QUERY",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'orders/view/{{order_id}}">{{value}} - Reference no.: {{reference_number}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Orders</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'invoices',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_invoices.json?q=%QUERY",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'invoices/view/{{invoice_id}}">{{invoice_number}} - {{company}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-file"></i> Invoices</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'services',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_services.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'services/view/{{rma_id}}">{{value}} - {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> RMA services</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'serials',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_serials.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'serials/view/{{serial_id}}">{{value}} - {{product}} {{module_name}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-barcode"></i> Serials</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'users',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_users.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'users?f=1&filter_id={{user_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}} - {{email}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-user"></i> Users</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'licenses',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_licenses.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'licenses?f=1&filter_id={{license_id}}">{{key}} - {{version}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Licenses</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'products',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_products.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'products?f=1&filter_id={{product_id}}">{{code}} - {{name}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Products</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'tasks',
        remote: {
            url: base_url+"utilities/ajaxprocess/typeahead_tasks.json?q=%QUERY%",
            maxParallelRequests: 8,
        },
        template: '<a href="'+base_url+'tasks?f=1&filter_id={{task_id}}">#{{task_id}} - {{description}}</a>',
        header: '<h5 class="search-result-header"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Tasks</h5>',
        engine: Hogan,
        limit: 6
    }
]).on('typeahead:selected', function($e, data) {
    window.location = data.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of such a limit, I wonder if there is a maximum amount of returned results that might be being satisfied by the first 6?

A quick test would be to essentially force a couple of your remote queries to always return nothing.

If your seventh search starts getting hit than that could explain it.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. It is not limited, but default max parallel request is 6. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this old question, and wants to increase the maxPendingRequests setting to more than 6 (or make it smaller), see [this PR](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/pull/62#issuecomment-186402183) I recently submitted to the maintained fork of typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

Open Twitter typeahead.js file.

Search for : "maxPendingRequests = 6"

Instead of 6 Just put whatever value you want.

Now i can see more than 6 requests run parallel.

It works fine for me.

Don't go for 'maxParallelRequests' property it doesn't work at all...

I am sure its the final solution.....